# Java: hashing every possible pair in a huge list

Tags: java, performance, hashmap

I have a list of strings that I want to get every possible pair out of it, 
so for example

```
items_List = [ "A","B","C","D" ]
```

the pairs would be

```
A-B
A-C
A-D
B-C
B-D
C-D
```

I would like to get all these pairs and put them in a

```
HashMap<String, Double>
```

such that "A-B" would be such a String and the Double would be some number that i'm going to compute in a separate function.
What I was doing is

```
for(int i=0; i< itemsList.length-1;i++){
        for(int j = i+1;j<itemsList.length;j++){
                a = itemsList[i];
                b = itemsList[j];
                Double w = compute_w(a,b);
                if(w>0) map.put(a+'-'+b, w);
        }
```

the problem is that my itemsList length is around n=400k items, so thats (n choose 2) number of pairs thats need to be hashed on max (w might be 0 in a really a lot of cases), nontheless the number of pairs is large, and it takes a really long time to compute all pairs (note: compute_w(a,b) is a simple function so it doesnt take that much to finish).
so my question is, is there any way i can do this efficiently and faster? 
I have tried setting the hashmap initial length to Integer.Max and the factor to 1.0 but that still didn't help.

any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you need these pairs for? It looks like you need an algorithm that doesn't need this data structure.

Comment: I want to pre-compute these numbers (w's) so that I can use them in another function

Comment: Precomputing 160 billion numbers may not be terribly useful. Does the other function require all 160 billion values?

Comment: the other function takes an item, a, and finds all pairs that contains a and does some averaging computations

Comment: Interesting, you may interested in building a rainbow table. the input space is 160 billions and it really a very big table to be stored in memory and even hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

Try to split your lookup structure into several maps

```
Map<String, Map<String, Double>> map = new HashMap<>(550000);
for (int i = 0; i < itemsList.length - 1; i++) {
    String a = itemsList[i];
    Map<String, Double> m = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(a, m);
    for (int j = i + 1; j < itemsList.length; j++) {
            String b = itemsList[j];
            double w = compute_w(a, b);
            if (w > 0) m.put(b, w);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try some kind of tree structure of like a 'trie' to conserve memory. If you store a huge list/hashmap of pairs A-B, A-C, A-D, etc, you are duplicating 'A' a bunch unnecessarily. If these pairs are long it could add up to a lot of wasted space. Instead you could have a root 'A' node and descendent nodes would be valid combinations resulting from 'A' and they would store the computed w value.

http://www.toptal.com/java/the-trie-a-neglected-data-structure